# Need help to create php curl for given URL

Tags: php

i am working to create php script to call INTERAC payment gateway url in php curl. It is required to call url into GET with https.  How to write it ?
Following is a test URL which works in browser but not working in CURL :

```
https://gateway.interpaycanada.com:1443/TERMID=TESTTERM&CARD=4111111111111111&EXP=10/0000&AMT=10040&REF=80062159&TYPE=S
```

When you test in browser then change any random new unique value in "REF".

I use following php curl script.

```
$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://gateway.interpaycanada.com:1443/TERMID=TESTTERM&CARD=4111111111111111&EXP=10/0000&AMT=10040&REF=80062159&TYPE=S");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'read_header');  
$response =curl_exec($ch);  

echo $response;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your curl add those lines:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 1443);
```

also after it make `print_r($response);`

About link:

```
https://gateway.interpaycanada.com:1443/TERMID=TESTTERM&CARD=4111111111111111&EXP=10/0000&AMT=10040&REF=80062159&TYPE=S
```

Delete `:1443`. So it will look like follows:

```
https://gateway.interpaycanada.com/TERMID=TESTTERM&CARD=4111111111111111&EXP=10/0000&AMT=10040&REF=80062159&TYPE=S
```

Your get data are stored in link with `key=value` for example: `CARD=4111111111111111`, more items you add with `&`.

**Debug**

You can check for errors inside a `curl` with

```
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
```

More informations about `CURL` options can be found in [PHP Manual: curl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

**Response from given url**

There might be a problem with given host, because my code still returns an error (connection refused by host:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('https://gateway.interpaycanada.com/TERMID=TESTTERM&CARD=4111111111111111&EXP=10/0000&AMT=10040&REF=80062159&TYPE=S');

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 1443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$result = curl_exec($ch);


 echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
echo file_get_contents('https://gateway.interpaycanada.com:1443/TERMID=TESTTERM&CARD=4111111111111111&EXP=10/0000&AMT=10040&REF=80062159&TYPE=S');

?>
```

With:

```
Curl error: Failed to connect to gateway.interpaycanada.com port 1443: Connection refused
```

and

```
failed to open stream: Connection refused
```

Also `fsockopen()` gives `Connection refused (111)`.

**Possible fix**

There is new option in PHP 7.0.7 like `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS`, so if you have this PHP version you can try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS, 0);
```

Comment: I tried but doesnot work. Page showing loading process for a long time and does not show any result.

Comment: still same issue. Page shows continue load process and does not do anything. Did you test it ?

Comment: Checking out, I dont yet why it doesn't work. Give me a sec please :)

Comment: Just remind that as per given docs response should be in text/plain.

Comment: Well it looks like this page refusing me an answer. I checked errors and it gives still `Curl error: Failed to connect to gateway.interpaycanada.com port 1443: Connection refused`

Comment: Is there any other way to call this url in php script. ?  I just want to get response of this in php script.

Comment: Even with `file_get_contents('url)` there is a problem `failed to open stream: Connection refused`

Comment: There might be a problem with veryfying certificate. There is an option which might work in PHP 7.0.7 + like: `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYSTATUS`

Comment: And why this certificate is wrong? That's unsafe... can't it be right? It should work if certificate is okay.

Comment: You already using it with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); ` in your code

Comment: suppose we have to write CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  in curl. Then how to write it ?

Comment: You have it in your code. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` you got it

Comment: but we have set false, and so i think perhaps this may be a reason. Not sure.

Comment: This `false` is because we want to disable SSL peer verifying.

Comment: Sorry mate, even if I want, my knowledge ends here. I would try it in PHP 7.0.7 + or ask that company to fix their certificate.

Comment: Tried even `fsockopen()` but there is also `unable to connect to ... Connection refused (111) `